# Deleting left and right panes on DNN 6.2.6

Tags: dotnetnuke-6

I am on DNN 6.2.6 and I want to make the content pane of my pages full screen. I want to remove the left and right panes. Can anyone help on how to remove these panes or reduce their width?

I tried searching on the internet and did everything I read by didn't help. I have added .DNNEmptyPane{display:none;} at the bottom of the skin.css file but didn't help. I also removed  and  and still didn't help.

Your assistance in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration is in your Skin files (**.ascx**).
You can look under

> Admin -> Skins

to find out which skin your site is using.

Check in here:

> **\Portals_default\Skins\YourSkin\YourSkin.ascx**

***NOTE***: Make a backup of this directory before modifying anything in case you need to roll back.

Comment: Inside my skin I found the following .ascx files. 2-Column-Left-Mega-Menu.ascx, 2-Column-Left-Standard-Menu.ascx, 2-Column-Right-Mega-Menu.ascx, 2-Column-Right-SocialProfile-Mega-Menu.ascx and 2-Column-Right-Standard-Menu.ascx. I removed <div id="LeftPane" runat="server"></div> and <div id="RightPane" runat="server"></div> in all these .ascx files.

Comment: You need to figure out which one its using and then inside that file is HTML and tags/tokens you can modify. Make a backup first!  You can make copies of the file and make changes to your copy.  Then, you just apply that skin to a test page through Admin->Skins.

Comment: Also, I'd highly recommend you watch some of the skinning video tutorials at: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/videos

Comment: I removed <%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LEFTMENU" Src="~/Admin/Skins/LeftMenu.ascx" %>, <div id="LeftPane" runat="server"></div> and <div id="RightPane" runat="server"></div>...it didn't help. Do you perhaps know specifically which tags do I need to modify?

Comment: My skin is going to be different from yours.  But, verify that you have the right one.  Also, if you put DNN in Layout mode, it will show you a wireframe of your layout and let you delete frames.  That way may, you can go back to your original skin and this may work better for you.  There are multiple ways to get this done.

Comment: The leftpane on mine skin is this: <td valign="top" class="leftpane" id="LeftPane" runat="server"></td>

Comment: Thanks for your help, I finally got a solution. The layout of DNN 6.2.6 is different from the layout in the earlier versions. Removing the tags helped. Thanks once again.